# Is it a security risk exposing an AC DC towards a different (local) Test Environment Network?

Tags: windows, security, domain

In my company, we have to build a small Test Environment on a separate network, which would supposed to be isolated from the Internet, except during the initial installation.

Due to restricted resources (time, money and manpower), we can't set up a new Windows Server with the AC DC installed on it just for this Test Environment.
The alternative is to be supported by the main company IT, in order to use the same DNS, DHCP, Authentication and everything else that it's already in place for the main Office activities.

However, it seems I can't convince them to allow this, as they motivate it with security risk and an overload of the DC.
For the overload, I don't think that adding 30 VMs would be a problem as the users would be the same, and instead of working on their Desktop, as they are doing now, they would work through RDP on the VMs.
For security reason, I don't know how to convince them that being a network separated from the network, and with authentication controlled by their DC, there is no risk, as it would be vice-versa from my point of view, as the Test Network would be connected to Office IT infrastructure exposed to the Internet.

Could I have a professional opinion on how to deal with such a scenario and if there are pros and cons in what we need, and how to proof the point?

Comment: AC DC?  Do you mean an AD (Active Directory) DC (Domain Controller) ?  By "motivate" you probably mean "equate".  "For security reasons".   Don't run VDI VMs on the same server as the DC, for performance reasons.  The security is less of an issue, compared to attempting to run non-DC functions on the DC.

Comment: I apologise for the misuse of the word "motivate" (lost in translation). What I meant is that they don't want to support my network with their infrastructure and services (DNS, DHCP, Authentication and Domain Users). Is it true that there is a security risk? Given the fact that my network is not exposed to the outside, but it would only be exposed to the IT Infrastructure indeed, in order to get the needed services.

Comment: This is a much larger problem than can be answered on a Q&A site.  You are correct in looking for a "professional opinion", which means hiring someone under NDA, giving them all details, and having them present a report.  The professional can tell you in detail any problems with your idea.  Possible security risks : Internet browsing from a server or virtually on the server; running 3rd party apps; 3rd party apps must be actively updated by IT.  Lastly, running VMs or virtual desktops takes a lot of CPU and RAM, so a new server is needed in addition to the DC.  IT is right to be cautious.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a few more details on your planned setup.

How are you separating your test network from the main network while still maintaining a connection to the main network's DC? Are the users who are connecting by RDP on the test network or are they outside of it?

The setup process for keeping a setup like this secure is probably going to be much more difficult for you (and the main company IT) than just spinning up a basic AD server for testing. Unless this is an extended test you could even just use the activation trial for Windows Server to avoid licensing.

Comment: To explain again there would be the Office IT, where we have physical desktop, and I need to create the Lab infrastructure. Yes this is an extended test infrastructure, it would be the "lab" in where to create our product, so the trial version is not an option. We don't even have resources and time to set up a Domain Controller.
The idea is to only allow traffic coming from the office and only RDP, SSH, DNS, DHCP, NTP traffic. But the IT Team says it's a security risk for the Office IT, and I would like to know how to make them understand is not, as my Lab test is not exposed to the outside